# How can I install libnetlink?

Tags: c, makefile, netlink

I'm trying to build my application with netlink library and need for already installed libnetlink.h header. So, I tried to install [this](https://github.com/iproute2/iproute2), but installation didn't installed netlink libraries. Then I tried [this](https://github.com/thom311/libnl). I dont know how author maintain this repo, but 3.9.0 library building with error. So, 3.8.0 is okay. But make install didn't installed my header. So the question is - where is that, which package should I install?

I know fedora have iproute2-dev package, but I'm on Debian and apt have no such package

Package libnl-3-dev also doesn't allow me for this headers

Comment: If you look at the [file list](https://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/amd64/libnl-3-dev/filelist), libnl-3-dev includes `/usr/include/libnl3/netlink/netlink.h`. Assuming you use the recommended compiler flags from `pkg-config`, that would be `#include <netlink/netlink.h>`.

Comment: Yes, I already installed it, but it didn't help me. And netlink/netlink.h with libnetlink.h are not the same

Comment: For example, this repo using this well https://github.com/moises-silva/libnetlink-examples/blob/master/ifstate.c#L10

Comment: I'm not familar with this library, so maybe they're indeed different headers, but how do you know that? What if you try to use that one, does it lack some functions you need?

Comment: If there is a diversity of opinion on what the desired header's basename should be, then that may signal that there are multiple versions of the library available, such that you need to identify the right one for you.  If you need this for some other piece of third-party software, then the needed version might not be the most recent one.  But if you're building something of your own from scratch then using the most recent version available is probably the smart move.  Most likely that's the one in libnl-3-dev.